# ATX Motherboard with ATA password option and GNU/Linux compatibility

Tags: motherboard, linux, windows, encryption

I have two [Self Encrypting Drive (SED)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) and I'm using Debian as my main Operating System.

My current motherboard ([ASUS M5A97 R2.0](https://www.asus.com/fr/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/)) is GNU/Linux compatible (I had hard time to find a GNU/Linux compatible motherboard) but don't have any option in the BIOS to set ATA passwords for my SEDs, so I can't use the built-in encryption of my drives.

The motherboard should (be) :

- AMD compatible (AM3+)
- GNU/Linux and Windows compatible
- Have built-in support for Self Encrypting Drives
- ATX form factor

TPM support and others functionalities of current motherboards would be appreciated.

Comment: Related : https://serverfault.com/questions/695495/how-to-find-mainboards-that-supports-self-encrypting-device-sed-in-bios, http://www.tb-kaiser.de/ahci_sbe/

Answer (score 2):

After several calls/mails to the 4 major "grand public" motherboard manufacturer, it's was either a non-understanding/no response or we will call you back later to have more details.

It's seems they don't want to implement it do to the fear that novice user will look themselves out of their SEDs.

I was only be able to speak with the [technical support of ASRock](http://support@asrock.nl) (here the raw answer) :

> All our Intel 100 Series Mainboard have this function. Built in.
>
> Our AMD mainboards not. But it might be possible to make a new BIOS
>   for that.
>
> I can check with BIOS department, if they can provide
>   special BIOS for the mainboard you wish to have…

So basically you should buy [ASRock motherboards](http://www.asrock.com/mb/index.fr.asp) if you want this, either directly if it's a Intel 100 series or if not, asking before buying if they can make you a custom BIOS with this option for the board you are willing to buy.